# ¿Cómo comparar el contenido de una variable con una cadena de caracteres en MATLAB?

Tags: condiciones, variables, input, matlab

quería hacer un if que comprobara si el contenido de una variable el cual ha sido introducido por el usuarioes igual a una cierta cadena. Si el usuario escribe si no hay ningún problema, pero si escribe cualquier otra cosa da error.
El código que he puesto es el siguiente:

```
respuesta = input("¿Quiere ver la información?");
if respuesta == "si"
   disp("Información")
end
```

El error que da la consola es el siguiente:

```
Error using input
Unrecognized function or variable 'no'.

Error in pruebas (line 4)
a = input("A:");
```

¿Cuál es el fallo? Y, ¿cómo se podría solucionar? Se que es algo muy básico en la programación, pero estoy iniciándome y no he encontrado la solución en Internet. Gracias.